# Excel 2016 to open in the same place we closed it, like Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016

Slow to the game, I know, but I just upgraded to Office 2016 from Office 2010.  In 2010 when I opened Excel, it opened on the same screen, in the same position, no matter how many instances I opened... they just opened on top of each other.

In 2016, the first instance opens where it should -- ie. where I last closed it -- but, all subsequent instances open at what seems to be a random position on display #1, each with a downward-right offset from the previous one.

How do I get Excel 2016 to open all instances in the same location on the same display as the first instance?

Comment: You don't. It doesn't work like that anymore. Just curious: why would you upgrade to a version that is already 6 years behind the current release??

Comment: It's what I had.  Plus, from what I'm gathering, 2021 has the same usability issues as 2016 with respect to windows placement.

Comment: I don't know that this is an issue with Excel but with Windows.

Comment: If you don't mind it being maximized, the problem goes away with maximized windows. Otherwise, you will need software that that fixes the placement of any window.

Comment: Also, it does seem to matter that subsequent office windows open on the display it was launched. If you open a new instance and then quickly move your mouse to the other screen, chances are high that it opens on the correct monitor.

Comment: This is a matter of product design, and each generation of excel has its own style.